# Disable Silverlight, for a single page, using Greasemonkey or similar?

Tags: silverlight, firefox, greasemonkey

Hotmail does not work with Firefox and Silverlight enabled(in my case). Disabling Silverlight allows Hotmail to work BUT of course prevents Silverlight applications from running.

Is there any way to disable Silverlight for a single URL without too much work?

Answer (score 0):

Greasemonkey cannot do this since, it doesn't give you the requisite browser-chrome privileges and Microsoft does not provide javascript accessible hooks for this (as best I can determine, based on a quick search).

If you use [the *QuickJava* Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/), it gives you a handy button to quickly enable/disable Silverlight.

But, if you want to control this automatically, an a page-by-page basis, you will have to [write your own extension](http://crossrider.com/).

Comment: Writing the extension probably would not be difficult but how does one disable silverlight from javascript on a page by page basis?

Comment: You can't, unless you add that hook in the extension you write.  It would probably be easier to just have your extension track pages, rather than trying to provide an API for JS.

Comment: Huh? I'm trying to disable silverlight in an external html page. This means I need to modify the page(I'd imagine I can do this in gs). There is some check on the html page to determine if silverlight is installed. I simply need for the check to fail.

Comment: Link to that page.  That page's check may be outside of JS, but if it uses JS, then you may be able to thwart it on a case-by-case basis.  Your question made it seem like you were after a more general approach.